# junit testcase for test returning object

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a method in which the return type is Object. How can I create testcase for this? How to mention the result should be a object?

My exact method is here.

```
public Object getData(String type, String expression)
{
    // do something here
    return Object;
}
```

How can I write a testcase for this method?

Comment: expression value --> //orders/value>500, type --> xpath

Comment: You probably want to tell us what the method is trying to do? What are the pre and post conditions?

Comment: i need junit testcase for this method to test

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to rename your method createXXX and give it a more interesting return type. Then you can build some test to build a specific object of a specific type and test if it corresponds to what you expect.

All those factory methods can share a common kernel that you can test seperatly.

Have a specific method for each type built means having a specific test for each method, it will be more clear for everyone and easier to test.

If all your return types share a common behavior that you can use for testing, then put this in an interface and set the return type to be an interface.

To soum up, having a method whose return type is object obliges every caller to subclass the result, knowing more or less the inner worjk of your method and this is a bad idea : clients will have to change when service interns change. You would be better to provide something more stable like returning an object with a given interface to interact with.

Answer (score 0):

You could test that the Object is not null.

The test that the Object is of the correct type you are looking for.

Or...

Have it return a concrete class.

Paul